# Hashing vs. Signing Binaries

Tags: security

If you want to ensure that a file is valid (untampered and came from the correct/expected source), there are two things you can do: **hashing**, and **signing**.

For the purposes of my question, **hashing** means providing a hash of the file (along with the file) to download. The client downloads the hash and the file, re-computes the hash, and verifies that it matches the downloaded hash; this "proves" that the file was untampered with.

**Signing** means using a public-private encryption scheme, where you sign the binary with a public key, and the client uses the private key to verify that you really did sign the key.

Based on these definitions, I don't really see what is the main benefit of signing something vs. hashing something. Both of them are supposed to prove that the file was not tampered with.

The only thing I can see is that with hashing, a compromised server could mean someone also compromising the hash and replacing a malicious binary with a matching key; but with a public-private scheme, as long as the private key remains private, there is no way to forge a malicious file.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MattBall in that case, please nominate it for moving over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is as you said: a hacker can update a hash to match the tampered-with file, but cannot generate a valid signature.

Signing is done with the private key, verification with the public key. You said the opposite above. It's also typically done on the hash of the file and not the file itself for practical reasons.

Comment: What prevents you from replacing the public key?

Comment: Hacker can generate a private-public key pair, and generate a signature accordingly. The best and clearest answer is of Matt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828053/hashing-vs-signing-binaries/7828109#7828109

Comment: @IamTheWalrus and author, that should be cracker, not hacker. Those who do bad things are crackers, not hackers. In fact, SO is a community of hackers. See http://stallman.org/articles/on-hacking.html.

Answer (score 8):

Signing verifies two things -- that the file has not been tampered with, **and** the identity of the signer.  If you can be sure that entity giving you the hash is absolutely the entity that is supposed to be giving you the file, then the two are equivalent.  Signing and certificate authorities are a way of ensuring that trust relationship.

Comment: I recently downloaded a file and its signature. I downloaded the public key corresponding to that signature from three different public sources and verified that they match. Then I verified the file and got a good signature and the correct fingerprint. Is there any point at all to now manually compute a hash of this file and match this hash also or is this step redundant?

Answer (score 5):

The big difference between providing some data (an executable a document, whatever) along with a hash and providing the same data with a signature is with the hash, both the data and the hash value come from the same place.  So, if someone can compromise one of them, he can probably also compromise the other.

For example, if I can hack into your web server, I can easily replace your executable with my own version and replace the hash value with the correct hash for my executable.

If you sign your executable, I can't just produce another signature for a different executable and replace your original signature.  The signature verifies both the hash of the original data (the data has not changed since being signed) and that the signature was generated by your private key.

Of course, this all assumes that people who receive your signed executable have received your public key in some trusted way.  If I can trick people into using my public key instead of yours, then I can hack into your website and replace your signed executable with my own.  That's why we have certificate authorities.

[This page](http://www.youdzone.com/signature.html) has a high level overview of digital signatures.

Answer (score 5):

Hash is a output with fixed length of characters(or bits if represented in binary) for a specific data that is passed into a function. 
Hash is irreversible.The hash value for a particular data is always same. If a single bit in data changes almost entire hash for the altered data is changed. The process of calculating a hash is called hashing.

In Asymmetric cryptography each communicating party has his own key pair (private key and public key). As name suggest , private key is usually kept secret and public key is shared. These keys are as such in nature that if one is used to encrypt then the only other key pair can decrypt.

To achieve non repudiation(sender cannot deny he sent message) and to Authenticate specific entity to receive data , public key is shared to them so that they can decrypt anything that is encrypted by the sender using the corresponding private key that is with the sender(only with sender i.e secret)
But note that confidentiality is week in this example as sender does not know and cannot guarantee if public key was compromised to an unknown.

when private key is used to encrypt a Hash then it becomes a signature and the process is called signing. This achieves Authenticity (that data is coming from a genuine guy as private key is used) and also Integrity is assured because receiver verifies the Hash upon receiving data by decrypting the hash using corresponding public key given to him by sender and then calculating the same hash on his own and matching it.