# How can I verify the Git-Installer via Hash?

Tags: git, hash, md5, sha256, pgp

Is there any way to verify the Windows-download?
I couldn't find a hash on the official git site

Comment: Do you mean [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), or [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)? Those are two very different things, and your title says GitHub but your question body isn't as clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Git and GitHub are very different things. Your question isn't clear about which it refers to. I'm pretty sure you either mean the GitHub Desktop installer or the Git for Windows installer.

The [official Git for Windows project does publish SHA-256 hashes for its releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).

GitHub doesn't publish hashes of its installers but it does [sign them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/digital-signatures-and-windows-installer), which is [even better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7828053/354577). Right-click the installer, go to Properties, then to Digital Signatures.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the Git-Installer from https://git-scm.com/ :D

Comment: @John, the [Windows download from git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/download/windows) is Git for Windows: "You are downloading the latest (**2.21.0**) **32-bit** version of **Git for Windows**. This is the most recent [maintained build](https://git-for-windows.github.io/). It was released **about 1 month ago**, on 2019-02-26." Use the SHA-256 hashes published on GitHub as I linked in my question.